# add custom citation that differs in format than the rest

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

This has been bugging me for quite some time now but can't find a nice way to work it out.

I have a list of citations that follow the regular author. Year. Title. Journal. Volume: Pages layout. I have to cite a legal document (Water framework directive). How do I go about this, as the paper has no authors, journals, pages...

I would like it to appear in the text as

> ... V Sloveniji smo leta 2000 sprejeli
>   *Vodno direktivo (2000/60/EC)* (v
>   nadaljevanju: VD), ki v evropskem
>   prostoru enotno ureja politiko
>   upravljanja površinskih in podzemnih
>   celinskih voda, vključno s somornico
>   in morjem....

and in the references as

> Ter Braak, C. J. F., Verdonschot, P. F. M. 1995. Canonical correspondence analysis and related multivariate methods in aquatic ecology. Aquatic Sciences 57(3): 255–289.
>
> *Vodna direktiva (2000/60/EC)*
>
> Wickham, H. 2009. ggplot2: elegant graphics for data analysis. Springer New York. ISBN 978-0-387-98140-6.

How should I specify my BibTeX source to achieve this?

*EDIT*

This is a more or less minimal working example. Style file can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8161901/custom_style.bst), and the bib file [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8161901/test.bib).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

As specified in \citet{vd} and \citep{Fraschetti2006} \dots

\bibliographystyle{custom_style}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

*EDIT 2*

A workaround that worked for me (for now). The four questionmarks in question (hehe) were the result of missing year in the bib file. I have modified the custom_style.bst from

```
FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    {
      "empty year in " cite$ * "; set to ????" * warning$
       pop$ "????"
    }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label *
}
```

to

```
   FUNCTION {format.date}
    { year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
        {
          "empty year in " cite$ * "; set to " * warning$
           pop$ ""
        }
        'skip$
      if$
      extra.label *
    }
```

Comment: Isn't there an @other bibentry?

Comment: There is, but doesn't help. I still get four question marks in bibliography.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that even legal documents should be represented by a BibTeX entry with more than one field (and especially with a `year` field if one uses an author-year-style), but here goes.

- I used the `author` instead of the `title` field because BibTeX otherwise would typeset the label `V00` in the text.
- The second pair of curly braces prevents BibTeX from breaking the "author" down in first name and last name.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{V00,
  author = {{\textit{Vodna direktiva (2000/60/EC)}}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

As specified in \citet{V00} \dots

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Better, but I still get four question marks in the bibliography (no title?).

Comment: @romunov Looks fine to me. Are you sure you re-ran BibTeX before then running LaTeX?

Comment: @WillRobertson, quite. This is my command sequence: pdflatex diploma; bibtex diploma; pdflatex diploma; pdflatex diploma. I'm not using the default citation style, though.

Comment: @romunov: It may well be that styles other than plainnat refuse to handle entries without a `title` field. What style do you use?

Comment: Because my faculty demands its own style for bibliography, I had to construct my own.

Comment: @romunov: Does my example work for you? If yes, we need details about your style (or even better: a working example).

Comment: I have added an example and a workaround. Is there a better way to handle this?